# Cog vs Triton Inference Server

Tags: production, replicate, triton, tritonserver

I'm considering [Cog](https://github.com/replicate/cog) and [Triton Inference Server](https://github.com/triton-inference-server/server) for inference in production.
Does someone know what is the difference in capabilities as well as in run times between the two, especially on AWS?